# Tem alguma forma de Pegar o caminho completo para importar um Arquivo csv?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Como descrito no título da minha dúvida, gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de pegar como parametro o caminho ate um arquivo csv, no caso eu preciso desse caminho para importar automaticamente o arquivo.

Minha tentativa de fazer isso é essa.
form

```
<%= form.file_field :file %>
```

Esse input que estou usando para pegar o arquivo e o simbolo `:file` como parametro para retornar o caminho.

users_controller

```
def create
@user = User.new(user_params)
binding.pry

require 'csv'

CSV.foreach(@user.file, col_sep: ',').with_index do |l, i|
  unless (indice == 0)
    User.create!(name: l[0], email: l[1], address: l[2])
  end
end

respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
    format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Usei o Binding.pry para mostrar o resultado que esta me retornando, e também o motivo da minha pergunta. Quando vou verificar os parametros que veio para o `user_params` é mostrado esse tipo de informação:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xb454db98 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20190710-3063-2ah7nt.csv>, @original_filename="users.csv", @content_type="text/csv", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[file]\"; filename=\"users.csv\"\r\nContent-Type: text/csv\r\n">} permitted: true>
```

OK. Agora vou mostrar o o que tem dentro do parametro `file` quando eu executo `@user.file` no console do pry.

```
"#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xb454db98>"
```

Muito bem, eu gostaria de saber se tem uma forma de retornar o caminho até o arquivo ou converter esse `"#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xb454db98>"` no caminho ate o arquivo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vc chegou perto, usando o proprio pry, vc consegue "entrar" nos objetos, como se fossem diretórios.

Vc poderia ter feito cd @user.file e lá ter dado um ls.

Vc veria os métodos que o objeto tem, entre eles o path que faz o que vc quer:

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile.html#method-i-path